# Approximate the Fisher information matrix of a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution, fisher-information

For $d\geq 2$, consider the d-dimensional multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal N(x|\mu,\Sigma)$ whose the log of density is given by
$$
l(x;\mu,\Sigma)=-\frac{d}{2}\log(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2}\log|\Sigma|-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^\top\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)
$$
here $\mu=(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_d)^\top$ and $\Sigma=(\sigma_{ij})_{d\times d}=\Sigma^\top$. I know that using identities from [Matrix cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/edoc/imm3274.pdf)
$$
\nabla_{\mu,\Sigma} l =(\frac{\partial l}{\partial\mu},\frac{\partial l}{\partial\Sigma})\equiv l_1(x;\mu,\Sigma)=\left( \Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu),-\frac{1}{2}\Sigma^{-1}+\frac{1}{2}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)(x-\mu)^\top\Sigma^{-1} \right)^\top. 
$$

[The Fisher information matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information):
The Fisher Information is defined as the covariance matrix, which in this case is given by

$$
\begin{align}
F&=\mathbb{E}_{X \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)}[l_1(X;\mu,\Sigma) l^\top_1(X;\mu,\Sigma)]
\\&\approx\frac{1}{S}\sum_{i=1}^Sl_1(x_i;\mu,\Sigma)l^\top_1(x_i;\mu,\Sigma)\in\mathbb{R}^{[d+d(d+1)/2]\times [d+d(d+1)/2]},\quad x_i\sim N(x|\mu,\Sigma)
\end{align}
$$
Note that I am aware that there is a closed-form for $F$ but I just wanted to use its approximation $\frac{1}{S}\sum_{i=1}^Sl_1(x_i;\mu,\Sigma)l_1^\top(x_i;\mu,\Sigma)$ to test its accuracy.

My question: Since the component of $l_1(x;\mu,\Sigma)$ is a mixture of a vector and a matrix, how I can compute the sum $\frac{1}{S}\sum_{i=1}^Sl_1(x_i;\mu,\Sigma)l_1^\top(x_i;\mu,\Sigma)$ or in particularly the factor $l_1(x_i;\mu,\Sigma)l^\top_1(x_i;\mu,\Sigma)$? Is there a neat way to do it ?

Comment: Welcome to CV, KNN :-). Did you derive the formula for $\nabla_{\mu,\Sigma} l =(\frac{\partial l}{\partial\mu},\frac{\partial l}{\partial\Sigma})$ yourself, or have you seen it somewhere? (I am asking because it could be here where the difficulties start, $\frac{\partial l}{\partial\mu}$ and $\frac{\partial l}{\partial\Sigma}$ are probably meant as shortcuts)

Comment: :) I did it myself using the cookbook of course. I am aware that there is a debate about $\frac{\partial l}{\partial\Sigma}$ but it is a minor problem for now.

Comment: The problem is that you need a parametric model for the Fisher information to make sense. You are talking about $\mu,\Sigma$ - there could be as many as $d + d(d+1)/2$ parameters in that model, including all the means, variances and covariances between the different components of the multivariate vector. Writing $\nabla_{\mu,\Sigma} l =(\frac{\partial l}{\partial\mu},\frac{\partial l}{\partial\Sigma})$ disguises the true dimensionality. Try to specify your multivariate model by a vector of parameters.

Comment: thanks Ute: $\theta=\theta_{1:d}$ is the vector of parameter. You can think it is the coefficient of a Bayesian linear regression. I am sorry that I may have  missed what you said.

Comment: How does this parameter affect the elements of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$? You need to calculate the derivative of log likelihood for $\theta$, not for $\mu,\Sigma$. Then you should get a $d\times d$ Fisher information matrix.

Comment: I changed it to log of density to avoid confusion ! given data y, we can to use Bayes' rule to estimate the parameters of $\theta$ which are $\mu,\Sigma$ in this case.

Comment: Sorry, the edit does not make sense to me :-( - you replaced data $x$ by $\theta$. Better roll back the edit.

Comment: sorry could you please tell me where it does not make sense ? I am very slow on this.

Comment: What does $(\theta - \mu)$ mean? Maybe you need some better / easier to read references about the theory - where did you read about Fisher information? In which context do you want to use it? Has it something to do with regression?

Comment: Ute: thanks for your time on this. I really appreciate it. Would this enough to explain
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/533527/fisher-information-as-negative-log-likelihood?rq=1?

Comment: KNN, I was wondering if you need help on the concept of parametric models. Normally one uses the symbol $\theta$ for parameters of a model, and $x$ for the data. In a $d$-variate Normal distribution with mean vector $\mu$, you could say $\theta_1=\mu_1,\theta_2=\mu_2$ and so on. Then you still need either more parameters for the covariance matrix $\Sigma$, or you have to make assumptions about it (or both). (The question you linked do does not provide information about these concepts) . The $\theta_1\dots$ are one dimensional numbers.

Comment: Ute: thanks again  but can we just focus on the main point: The Fisher Information is defined as the covariance matrix, or $E_{\theta \sim N(\theta|\mu,\Sigma)}[ \nabla_{\mu,\Sigma} log(N(\theta|\mu,\Sigma)) \nabla_{\mu,\Sigma} log(N(\theta|\mu,\Sigma))^T]$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148039/discussion-between-ute-and-knn).

Comment: There is a nice result for multivariate case see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information, For multivariate normal case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** part of the answer refers to an old version of the question, and was fixed by OP since. I think that this could confuse other users, too, and keep it therefore.

> The Fisher information: $$
> F=\mathbb{E}[l_1^\top l_1]\approx\frac{1}{S}\sum_{i=1}^Sl_1^\top(x_i)l_1(x_i)\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d},\quad x_i\sim N(x|\mu,\Sigma)
> $$

Your confusion seems to stem from assuming that the parameter space of a $d$-dimensional normal distribution $N(\mu,\Sigma)$ also has dimension $d$. If you do not put any restrictions on $\mu$ and $\Sigma$, you have more than $d$ free parameters: $d$ parameters alone would specify the mean vector $\mu$, on top of which you have additionally up to $d(d+1)/2$ parameters for the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ (they cannot all vary completely freely, though).

You need to express all parameters in your model as a vector, and then write the likelihood in dependence of the elements of your parameter vector.
When you take the derivative of the log likelihood, you will do this with respect to the $p$ elements of the actual parameter vector of your model. The resulting Fisher information is a $p\times p$ matrix, not a $d\times d$ matrix.

Here are two examples for statistical models of two dimensional normal distributions. Write
$$\mathbf(X)_i=(X_{1i}, X_{2i})\sim N(\mu,\Sigma), \quad \mu=(\mu_1,\mu_2),\ \ \Sigma=\pmatrix{\sigma_1^2 & \gamma\\\gamma&\sigma_2^2}$$ where $\gamma=\mathrm{Cov}(X_1,X_2)$.

###### 1.) Components with different means and variances and unknown covariance $\gamma$.

The parameter vector is $\theta=(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_5)=(\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma^2_1,\sigma_2^2,\gamma)$. It has the restrictions that $\sigma_1^2>0, \sigma_2^2 > 0$, and $\gamma\in[-\frac{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}{2},\frac{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}{2}]$ . So $p=5$ here.

In this example, write
$$
\begin{multline}
l(x;\theta) = -\frac{2}{2}\log(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2}\log\left|\pmatrix{\sigma_1^2 & \gamma\\\gamma&\sigma_2^2}\right|-
\\ \frac{1}{2}(x_1-\mu_1, x_2-\mu_2)\pmatrix{\sigma_1^2 & \gamma\\\gamma&\sigma_2^2}^{-1}\pmatrix{x_1-\mu_1\\x_2-\mu_2}
\end{multline}
$$
which gives a moderately lengthy expression. Take the partial derivatives with respect to $\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma^2_1,\sigma_2^2,\gamma$.

###### 2.) Independent components with same variance but different means.

Then $\gamma=0$, $\sigma_1^2=\sigma_2^2=\sigma^2$ and you have a $p=3$ dimensional parameter vector $\theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)=(\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma^2)$. It has the restriction that $\sigma^2>0$.

In this example, the log likelihood is
$$
\begin{aligned}
l(x;\theta) &= -\frac{2}{2}\log(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2}\log\left|\pmatrix{\sigma^2 & 0\\0&\sigma^2}\right|-
\\ &\qquad\frac{1}{2}(x_1-\mu_1, x_2-\mu_1)\pmatrix{\sigma^2 & 0\\0&\sigma^2}^{-1}\pmatrix{x_1-\mu_1\\x_2-\mu_2}
\\&=-\frac{1}{2}\left(2\log 2+\log\sigma^4+\frac{(x_1-\mu_1)^2}{\sigma^2}+\frac{(x_2-\mu_2)^2}{\sigma^2} \right)
\\&=-\log 2 -\log\sigma^2-\frac{(x_1-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{(x_2-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2} .
\end{aligned}
$$
Take the partial derivatives with respect to $\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma^2$:
$$
l_1(x;\theta)=\nabla_{\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma^2} l = \left(\frac{x_1-\mu_1}{\sigma^2},
\frac{x_2-\mu_2}{\sigma^2},-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}+\frac{(x_1-\mu_1)^2+(x_2-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^4}\right)^\top.
$$
This is a three dimensional vector, and $l_1(x;\theta)l_1(x;\theta)^\top$ is consequently a $3\times 3$ matrix.
(Note that $\sigma^2$ counts as a symbol for $\theta_3$ when taking the deriative).

Comment: thank you Ute. but this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I have extended the answer - does it help?

Comment: Thanks Ute ! I fixed the typos ad indeed your extended answer helps alot.

Comment: +1! I can see that you got the grip of it :-)